# Global variable is stubborn

Tags: javascript, variables

Why is my global variable being stubborn?

Here's my simplified code snippet:

```
window.bVar = false;    
function iChange() {
          bVar = true;
          alert( bVar ); // 'true'
          }
// some event calls iChange function
window.onbeforeunload = alert( bVar ); // 'false'
```

The alert always shows 'false' (unless I alert within the function).

I have also tried using `var bVar = false` to set the global variable.

Why won't my global variable change outside the scope of the function?

Comment: *"tried using `var bVar = false` to set the global variable"* That will explicitly **not** set the global variable. That will create a local variable and set that to `false`, completely unrelated to the state of the global variable with the same name.

Comment: Do you mean `window.onbeforeunload = function() { alert(bVar); }` ?

Comment: I love the concept that an inanimate variable can be "stubborn". Its a very human concept and Im afraid its you being stubborn :)

Comment: Yes, I'm the stubborn one, since it won't do what I want it to do - grrrr!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is really too short to be an answer which is why I wrote it in a comment, but you are immediately evaluating `alert(bVar)` instead of evaluating it as part of the onbeforeunload listener.  You need something like this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() { alert(bVar); };
```

Comment: However, as has been discussed on here before, most browsers will block this alert as a security feature.  You should probably do something more like `window.onbeforeunload = function() { return bVar; }`

Comment: Yes, the line "window.onbeforeunload = alert( bVar );" immediately sets the value of onbeforeunload to whatever is returned by "alert()", which is undefined. onbeforeunload needs to be set to a function, as astex says.

Comment: To be less succinct and more specific, I want to call another function, no real need to alert. The other function will do a .load and write values to a database. So should this work? ;cause it doesn't pass the updated value of the global variable :(

window.onbeforeunload = function() { dosomethingelse(bVar); }

function dosomethingelse(bVar) { }

Answer (score 0):

To be less succinct and more specific, I want to call another function, no real need to alert. The other function will do a .load and write values to a database. So should this work? ;cause it doesn't pass the updated value of the global variable :( for instance ...

```
var bVar = "value";
window.onbeforeunload = function() { dosomethingelse( bVar ); } 
function dosomethingelse( bVar ) { $("#id").val( bVar ); }
```